# What's a word for a voice doppelganger?

Tags: word-choice

Someone that looks exactly like you is a dead ringer or a doppelganger.  But what if they just *sound* exactly like you?

Comment: I'm not aware of any single word for this.  I'd probably call them a *vocal twin* which would, I believe, be immediately obvious, but it is not a commonly recognized idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**voice double** (n.)

> Like stunt doubles or digital retouching, voice matching — also known
> as "**voice double**" or "**soundalike**" — is a tool the movie
> business uses to conjure the fantasy we imagine in our heads. It's a
> process in which voiceover artists are hired in postproduction to come
> in and double for the voice of a star. ["Here's the trick directors
> use when they can't get stars to finish a movie";
> businessinsider.com](https://www.businessinsider.com/voice-matching-in-movies-2016-3)

> Before the release of *The Unholy Three,* many stories circulated
> stating that Chaney wouldn't speak in any role or that he might use a
> **voice double** (although the technique for dubbing had yet to be perfected). [Michael Blake; *A Thousand Faces*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Thousand_Faces/oE-UET_HsHkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22he%20might%20use%20a%20voice%20double%22&pg=PA282&printsec=frontcover)

> The audiovisual contract permes audiences of mainstream films to
> expect that a character will sound very different when she sings than
> when she renders dialogue. Specifically, a character will have a
> different voice in the song sequence than she does in other,
> nonmusical sequences. In the 1940s, Bombay filmmakers tried to match
> the singer's voice to the voice and personality of the actor. This
> practice of **voice-casting** quickly faded as playback voices came to
> be lauded for their own qualities, rather than for being a **voice
> double** of the actor. [T. Whittaker and S. Wright; *Locating the
> Voice in Film*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Locating_the_Voice_in_Film/DvK4DQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22voice%20double%22&pg=PA67&printsec=frontcover)

> Nevertheless, when Durâteu starts to act as a "**voice double**" under
> the pseudonym Tristan Vox in Felix's radio show, the voice and body
> form a perfect match in one single person. [Mikko Keskinen; *Audio
> Book*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Audio_Book/IH8fcGQiokAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22voice%20double%22&pg=PA37&printsec=frontcover)

> Rather than employ a **voice double** for his Norwegian star, Hughes
> fired Greta Nissen and replaced her with an unknown Jean Harlow, in
> the role that made the latter made the actress a star. [Arne Lunde;
> *Nordic Exposures*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Nordic_Exposures/krlcCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22voice%20double%22&pg=PA105&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 12):

***[soundalike](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/soundalike)*** (or sound-alike)

> a person or thing that sounds like another, especially a better known or more famous prototype:
>
> *a whole spate of Elvis Presley soundalikes.*

---

Also, ***vocal doppelganger*** is used colloquially. There is even a few results in [Google books](https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=8IKrU7OfB8eC8QeFzIEI&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22vocal%20doppelganger%22&safe=off&tbm=bks).

Answer (score 1):

I'd call it `gesangsdoppel`, which is German for vocal double and sounds kind of neat.

Comment: Hello, Evan. Gesangsdoppel seems rare even in German-speaking countries/areas, and is off-topic on ELU as certainly not in the English lexis.

Answer (score -2):

**Mimic**

Would seem to be the nearest English word. However this implies deliberate impersonation, rather than the coincidental similarity that the question implies.

If you consider that there is no English equivalent of the German “Doppelgänger”, then it is hardly surprising no aural equivalent exists when there is no word for this in German.

Shade!